# datatable dynamic formation from javascript

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am trying to draw a table dynamically from javascript, i could able to do it successfully, but when i want to navigate to pages via "lengthMenu" and next or previous, it is not working.

As well, when i try searching also it is not working.

```
$('#step5ResponseTable').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[1, 2], [1, 2]],
    columnDefs: [ {
         targets:   0
    } ]
} );

$("#step5ResponseTable").empty();
                         var th = '<thead>' + 
                         '<tr>'+
                         '<th> Device Name </th>'+
                         '<th> Status </th>'+
                         '<th> Reason </th>'+
                         '</tr>'+
                         '</thead>';
                         $('#step5ResponseTable').append(th);
                        for(var i=0; i < aa.length; i++){
                            var response = callAPI(JSON.stringify(aa[i]), i);
                                    var tr = '<tr>'+
                                     '<td>'+'Device'+'</td>'+
                                     '<td>'+'Success'+'</td>'+
                                     '<td>'+'HHH'+i+'</td>'+
                                     '</tr>';   
                                      $('#step5ResponseTable').append(tr);
                        }

<table class="display" cellspacing="0" id="step5ResponseTable">
                                        </table>
```

version of jquery.dataTables.min.js -> 1.10.13

jquery.dataTables.min.css

When i select 1 or 2 record per page, it does not work properly

Comment: You are initializing the datatable library before adding the data, this will not work. You should add the data first and then initialize your table.

Comment: ...And it would be way easier to create the <thead> and inserting rows using DataTable on an empty <table> tag.

Comment: @Jerodev you are correct, i tried initializing datatable libs after constructing table, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per the above comment from @Jerodev, i got it working as follows

```
$("#step5ResponseTable").empty();
                         var th = '<thead>' + 
                         '<tr>'+
                         '<th> Device Name </th>'+
                         '<th> Status </th>'+
                         '<th> Reason </th>'+
                         '</tr>'+
                         '</thead>';
                         $('#step5ResponseTable').append(th);
                        for(var i=0; i < aa.length; i++){
                            var response = callAPI(JSON.stringify(aa[i]), i);
                                    var tr = '<tr>'+
                                     '<td>'+'Device'+'</td>'+
                                     '<td>'+'Success'+'</td>'+
                                     '<td>'+'HHH'+i+'</td>'+
                                     '</tr>';   
                                      $('#step5ResponseTable').append(tr);
                        }
```

// after this i initialized the datatable

```
$('#step5ResponseTable').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[1, 2], [1, 2]],
    columnDefs: [ {
         targets:   0
    } ]
} );
```